# How do I setup a custom hostname for my IRC daemon?

Tags: dns, ircd, reverse-dns

I have a registered domain and I want to make `irc.mydomain.com` the domain which any public user can access through port 6667.

I'm currently running ircd-hybrid but it's only setup to accept localhost connections.

What's necessary on my end from the DNS side to make `irc.mydomain.com` point to my server, and connect to 6667?

From the config file of ircd, I see this:

```
324 connect {
325         /* name: the name of the server */
326         name = "irc.example.net";
327 
328         /* host: the host or IP to connect to.  If a hostname is used it
329          * must match the reverse dns of the server.
330          */
331         host = "127.0.0.1";
332 
333         /* passwords: the passwords we send (OLD C:) and accept (OLD N:).
334          * The remote server will have these passwords reversed.
335          */
336         send_password = "password";
337         accept_password = "password";
338 
339         /* compressed: controls whether traffic is compressed via ziplinks.
340          * By default this is disabled
341          */
342         compressed = no;
343 };
```

So, would I set the name to "irc.mydomain.com" and then in my DNS manager make a A-record entry so that irc.mydomain.com points to my server's IP address? Or is this procedure not necessary and I just need to make a PTR record?

Also, afterwards do I just update the host to be the public IP of my server? Or does it stay local? Again, I want it to be publicly accessible...

Comment: [Here is some config documentation](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/ircd/h7setup.html). I don't think you should be using the `connect {}` block.

Comment: My initial thought was to specify the vhost in the serverinfo, but there are no "real world" examples of it.. which makes it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your DNS managed and make 'irc.mydomain.com' a CNAME for the host's existing name. Alternatively, make it an A record with the correct IP address.

The 'connect' block has to do with outbound server-to-server connections.

Comment: Thanks, gonna do the A-recourd route. So the connect block is irrelevant? I would modify just the server info block? And what would I set the vhost and/or name to?

Comment: Set the name to whatever you want to call your server.